# Add common objects and format to arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to add a common array of objects, should be similar fund_asset_class_focus and year, and have to format into an array of arrays as below(`["fund_asset..","2017-total allocation",2018,2019]`).

```
data = [
  {
    "allocation": 60.30,
    "dt": "2017",
    "fund_asset_class_focus": "U.S. Fixed Income"
  },
  {
    "allocation": 50,
    "dt": "2017",
    "fund_asset_class_focus": "U.S. Fixed Income"
  }
  {
    "allocation": 39.80,
    "dt": "2018",
    "fund_asset_class_focus": "U.S. Fixed Income"
  },
  {
    "allocation": 40.7,
    "dt": "2019",
    "fund_asset_class_focus": "U.S. Fixed Income"
  },
  {
    "allocation": 20,
    "dt": "2018",
    "fund_asset_class_focus": "Cash"
  },
  {
    "allocation": 9.7,
    "dt": "2018",
    "fund_asset_class_focus": "Cash"
  }
  {
    "allocation": 16,
    "dt": "2018",
    "fund_asset_class_focus": "Credit"
  },
  {
    "allocation": 16,
    "dt": "2019",
    "fund_asset_class_focus": "Credit"
  },
  {
    "allocation": 16,
    "dt": "2019",
    "fund_asset_class_focus": "Credit"
  }
]

data = [["U.S. Fixed Income",110.30,39.80, 40.7],["Cash",0,29.7,0],["Credit",0,16,32]]
```

I tried to solve this by using the following code, however, it was unsuccessful in meeting my requirements:

```
for (let i in data) {
  var tempObj = {};
  if (obj[years[0]]) 
    tempObj[years[0]] = obj[years[0]];
  else
    tempObj[years[0]] = {};

  if (obj[data[i]["fund_asset_class_focus"]]) {

  }
}
```

Comment: 1) What have you tried so far? 2) Why do you want to use this output format? It seems to not be very optimal.

Comment: Please add the code you've tried so far

Comment: I am working on the skittle chart, where data to be an array of arrays

Comment: Can you please include a more detailed desired outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted it out using [lodash](https://lodash.com). Please use the below code.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "allocation": 60.30,
    "dt": "2017",
    "fund_asset_class_focus": "U.S. Fixed Income"
  },
  {
    "allocation": 50,
    "dt": "2017",
    "fund_asset_class_focus": "U.S. Fixed Income"
  },
  {
    "allocation": 39.80,
    "dt": "2018",
    "fund_asset_class_focus": "U.S. Fixed Income"
  },
  {
    "allocation": 40.7,
    "dt": "2019",
    "fund_asset_class_focus": "U.S. Fixed Income"
  },
  {
    "allocation": 20,
    "dt": "2018",
    "fund_asset_class_focus": "Cash"
  },
  {
    "allocation": 9.7,
    "dt": "2018",
    "fund_asset_class_focus": "Cash"
  },
  {
    "allocation": 16,
    "dt": "2018",
    "fund_asset_class_focus": "Credit"
  },
  {
    "allocation": 16,
    "dt": "2019",
    "fund_asset_class_focus": "Credit"
  },
  {
    "allocation": 16,
    "dt": "2019",
    "fund_asset_class_focus": "Credit"
  }
];

var years = _.uniqBy(data, 'dt').map(obj => obj.dt); // Get all available years ["2017", "2018", "2019"]

var result = _(data).groupBy('fund_asset_class_focus').map((objs, key) => [
  key,
  ...years.map(year => _.sumBy(_.filter(objs, obj => obj.dt === year), 'allocation'))
])
.value();

console.log(result); // [["U.S. Fixed Income",110.30,39.80, 40.7],["Cash",0,29.7,0],["Credit",0,16,32]]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.14/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you guide me any tutorials for lodash.

Comment: Go to https://lodash.com. It has tons of JavaScript functions for arrays and objects. You can just include the lodash JS library into your html.
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.14/lodash.min.js"></script>
You can use npm lib if you use ES6

Comment: Hi Kiran, can you please upvote the answer or mark it as accepted if you don't have any other question?

Answer (score 2):

Create a mapping object called `years` which will have each year as key and the year's position in the output array as it's value. Here, I'm assuming you have only 3 years. You could also make this dynamic. Then use `reduce`. Create an accumulator object with each `fund_asset_class_focus` as key the nested array you need in the output as value.

```js
const data=[{allocation:60.3,dt:"2017",fund_asset_class_focus:"U.S. Fixed Income"},{allocation:50,dt:"2017",fund_asset_class_focus:"U.S. Fixed Income"},{allocation:39.8,dt:"2018",fund_asset_class_focus:"U.S. Fixed Income"},{allocation:40.7,dt:"2019",fund_asset_class_focus:"U.S. Fixed Income"},{allocation:20,dt:"2018",fund_asset_class_focus:"Cash"},{allocation:9.7,dt:"2018",fund_asset_class_focus:"Cash"},{allocation:16,dt:"2018",fund_asset_class_focus:"Credit"},{allocation:16,dt:"2019",fund_asset_class_focus:"Credit"},{allocation:16,dt:"2019",fund_asset_class_focus:"Credit"}];

const years = { 2017: 1, 2018: 2, 2019: 3 },
      defaultValues = Object.keys(years).map(_ => 0);

const merged = data.reduce((r, o) => {
  const { allocation, dt, fund_asset_class_focus: fund } = o;
  r[fund] = r[fund] || [fund, ...defaultValues];
  r[fund][years[dt]] += allocation;
  return r;
}, {})

const output = Object.values(merged);

console.log(JSON.stringify(output))
```

Comment: @kiran you can [mark the answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255) by clicking on the grey checkmark next to it.